# How to share types between web services

Tags: asp.net, web-services

Team A creates WebServiceA. It will use type Person. When person is registered by call in WebServiceA the other system must also be notified (by call to WebServiceB created by Team B passing the registered person).

Then when person is edited in system B the modifications must be migrated to system A (by call to WebServiceA passing the person modified).

The question is how to make both WebServices use same type?
We could send xml as strings and then serialize/deserialize it to objects on each WebService's side so that we don't have to work with xml, but I'm curious if it is easier way to do it.

I would like to have this:

```
WebServiceA
Webmethod - RegisterPerson(Person person)
    calls WebServiceB.PersonRegistered(person)
WebMethod - PersonModified(Person person)

WebSericeB
WebMethod - PersonRegistered(Person person)
WebMethod - ModifyPerson(Person person)
    calls WebServiceA.PersonModified(person)
```

instead of this

```
WebServiceA
Webmethod - RegisterPerson(Person person)
    calls WebServiceB.PersonRegistered(person.SerializeToXml())
WebMethod - PersonModified(string person) - deserialize to WebServiceA.Person

WebSericeB
WebMethod - PersonRegistered(string person) - deserialize to WebServiceB.Person
WebMethod - ModifyPerson(Person person)
    calls WebServiceA.PersonModified(person.SerializeToXml())
```

We are using ASP.NET WebService in Team A and Team B is using Java.
Would it change anything if both teams were using .NET?

Answer (score 1):

If both teams were using .NET you could define your Data Objects in one class library project and both teams will share the same library (DLL). That's pretty much what Windows Communication Foundation does behind the scenes when you create a reference to a service in a .NET project. So it makes it simple to pass objects as parameters, just like in your first example.

Since you have two languages you definitely need common ground and that's where json or xml come into place (which is your second example). You could add some sort of converter classes that will capture a string, return your object and pass that as parameter to your methods, the implementation depends on the framework you are using (Spring makes this a breeze)

Comment: And what if we are using web services not wcf services? Is there a way to share objects between two web services written in .NET? I think you made a little error in your answer. I'm passing objects in first example not in second. In second I pass strings.

Comment: @Peri You can still create a proxy class (using a "web reference"). See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d9w023sx(v=vs.90).aspx. I believe WCF is the recommended way for web services though (btw I corrected my references to your examples).

Comment: Yes I know that I can create proxy class :) But when you add web reference then even though WebServiceB references same class library as WebServiceA types from this class library are regenerated together with proxy and are in different namespace. So if WebServiceB has method PersonRegistered(ClassLibrary.Person person) in WebServiceA it will be visible as PersonRegistered(WebService2.Person person).

Comment: @Peri Then you can still define your data object Person in a third class library. That way you have a "neutral" namespace (which is the first paragraph in my answer).

Comment: I don't understand. I add class library to solution. It contains Person class. I add two web applications with web service in each. Both reference class library and use Person type as input parameters to web methods. When you add web reference from WebServiceA to WebServiceB you can only pass WebServiceB.Person. You can't pass ClassLibrary.Person type. So you have three Person types. One you created and two generated (WebServiceA.Person, WebServiceB.Person).

Comment: This is indeed strange, did you figure it out?

Comment: I don't think that's possible with web services. Currently we added service reference (not web reference) to Java Web Service. Created objects by hand and decorated them with plenty of attributes (DataMember and many other I don't understand :)) and it works (if Java Web Service returns Person we see it as our Person). But I'm not really sure it is worth it.